# Unable to send mail via Google Mail Service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have two projects on Google App Engine, corresponding to two environments (one is for QA, the other for Production).

Currently the same code is running on both environments.

I have a problem though, I can't send emails in production while I can in QA. I can't find the differences, I read the documentation at least three times trying to figure it out.

In production I got the following exception:

```
Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1
```

While it is specifically written in the documentation that if I don't specify the SMTP host, it automatically uses the Mail Service API.

The mail senders are the same in both environments, with same rights (project owner).

If you have any suggestions/leads

Thank you

Comment: Do you have two versions of same Google APP Engine Application?

Comment: It's the same version on both environments

Comment: I do not understand this part "I have two projects on Google App Engine" . Do you have a QA project and Production Project ?

Comment: Yes, I have a QA project and a production project.

Comment: Check with infra team if there the app engine is given any different permissions on prod.

Comment: I am not sure, but I do not believe you can connect to port 25 on App Engine. Double check the port numbers between working/not-working services.

Comment: Actually I don't specify neither the host nor the port. And the documentation says : 

"When you create a JavaMail Session, if you do not provide any SMTP server configuration, App Engine uses the Mail service for sending messages. Alternatively, add SMTP configuration for supported third-party mail providers such as Mailgun, Mailjet, or SendGrid."

It worked well on the first env, but not on the second one.

Comment: What addresses are you sending from? Make sure you've set up the authorized senders list: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/#who_can_send_mail. Otherwise, I have no idea

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I did, the address I'm sending from is in the authorized senders list and has the "owner" role.

Comment: Could you please include in your question the code snippet of how you are sending the email from you app in AppEngine?